# How to adjust maximum Output Volume

Tags: sound, volume-control

The maximum output volume as allowed by the slider control in the menu bar is never loud enough. I have to open the Sound Settings and boost it past 100%.  This has been the case in 12.04, 12.10, and 13.04. Also, if the volume was set past 100% through sound settings, the use of volume shortcut keys cause the volume to slide back to 100%.

How can I adjust what Ubuntu considers 100% on the Output volume?

Comment: I think this is by-design.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean with 100%?
100% Its that...100% If you access to Sound Settings, There is a place where you can "Amplify" overpass 100% and get more "louder",  but is over level.
In same way, you can look at VLC where It's a volume level, that's 100% and you can amplify this to %200, but, is just that.
I recomend you a good pair of speaker system, or may be a nice pair of earphone to get better sound.

If you are over Level, you got a distortion of real sound.